# How to get the TextField position in a TableCell on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uitextfield

[image]

Here is the UI...(I know it is ugly...) The orange is a view, and the blue is the table, and the gray one is the table cell, lastly, the red is a textfield in a table cell. My question is simple, I just wanna to know the red text field position... Seems the table cell may move up and down, so, the position can be changed. So, I don't need to dynamic update the text field position, I just need the position when the user click the text field, any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: just to be clear, you want to know the position of the red view, relative to the orange view, right?

Comment: @calvinBhai yes, u r right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can make use of convetrPoint methods that can be used on an UIView or its derived classes

```
- (CGPoint)convertPoint:(CGPoint)point toView:(UIView *)view
- (CGPoint)convertPoint:(CGPoint)point fromView:(UIView *)view
```

in you case, you'll need to do this:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing(UITextField *)textField 
{
     CGPoint textFieldOriginInTableView = [textFiled convertPoint:textField.frame.origin toView:tableView];
     //or if you want it relative to the orangeView, your toView should be the orangeView
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There Are 2 thing I would like to mention:

1. If your textField is inside tabelViewCell, it's position is always same, no matter how much cell goes up or down. It's because textField is subview of tabelViewCell not of view.
2. You can get in several ways:

   - On `textFieldDidBeginEditing` delegate method (as you mentioned you need that when it is touched, means begin editing).
   - or when ever you want by following code:

   //you can set tag of text field

   ```
   UITableViewCell *cell = [yourTableView cellForrowAtIndexPath:yourCellIndexPath];
   UITextField *textField = (UITextField *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:textFieldTag];
   ```

   //OR don't wanna set Tag and only textfield is there

   ```
   for (UIView *v in [cell.contentView subviews]) {
     if ([v isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
         UITextField *textField = (UITextField *)v;
    }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the owning view controller is the UITextField's delegate, you can implement the textFieldDidBeginEditing: method and get the frame of the text field like so:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing(UITextField *)textField 
{
    CGRect rect = textField.frame;
}
```

Comment: The UITextField is belong to the cell, not the UIViewController.

Comment: That's the point Ted.. It'll always remain on that location.. frame inside cell..

Comment: @TedWong No need to worry about textField position if it is subView of cell. If you want to do position adjustments for textField, then do in cell's layOutSubview method.

Answer (score 0):

This code set frame with animation try this code...

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.2];
    CGRect youtTextFielfFrame = textField.frame;// get position of textfield from this code
    [textField setFrame:CGRectMake(textField.frame.origin.x - 50, textField.frame.origin.y,textField.frame.size.width,textField.frame.size.height)]; /// set frame which you want here......
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: @TedWong try this updated code here you can easily change the position of textfield with your required frame and also you can get position of textfield youtTextFielfFrame variable like above which i define dude..  hope this help you... :)

Comment: @TedWong it is help you dude??

Answer (score 0):

First add a unique tag to the textField

```
yourTextField.tag = 1001;
```

Than at the point where you want the position of your textField, simply do

```
UITextField *myTextField = [cell viewWithTag:1001];

CGRect textFieldRect = myTextField.Frame;
```

It will give you the frame of your tagged textField containing x,y,width,height parameters of your textField with respect to its superView.