# UITableView Auto scroll issue with sections having uitextfields

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uiscrollview

Scenario is: uitableview with multiple sections.Sections have multiple textfields in it. Now i want to properly scroll tableview on UITextfield active. i.e. whenever keyboard appears on view.
  There r number of solution available..such as.

```
[ tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:"name of current cell" atScrollPosition:"position to scroll" animated:YES];
```

here let "position to scroll"=UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle. ...
This is not 100% correct way,as design is not as required.

Another solution:

```
- (void)keyboardDidShow:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
// Managing contentInset and scrollIndicatorInsets of UITableView here. 
}..
```

This is also not correct. Any suggestions?

Comment: you can completely move view up when keyboard appearing.

Comment: yaah.i have  tried that with defalut initWithStyle of tableView. In that case TextField fides scrolls but behind Section Header which is not acceptable!!

Comment: view i mean UIView not only table view and try putting your header in table's header view and,  if possible show code along with methods what you have tried,

Comment: checking the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126726/how-to-make-a-uitextfield-move-up-when-keyboard-is-present

Comment: well...after some research ,i got thinks in place.            txtFieldOriginInTableView=[cellLocal.txtPoints convertPoint:cellLocal.txtPoints.frame.origin toView:tableMain];  .. give me the  textfields posion in Table View. and some calculation for proper scrolling done the trick!!!...  Thankx to  http://stackoverflow.com/a/13926438/4091144    answer by Nitin Alabur.